# How to subtract a dateTime from dateTime.Now() using TimeAgo package flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using `timeago` package in Flutter. I have a date and I want to show it like `timeago`.

Example: Now time is 3:26 and the date is 3:00. So I want it to be printed like 26 min ago.

My code is:

```
Widget _getTimeWidget(DateTime d){
        final dt = new DateTime.now().subtract(d);
        return new Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 31),
            child: Text(timeago.format(dt))
        );
  }
```

But, there is an error, the subtract function must be the duration.

Answer (score 1):

You received this error as the wrong value type has been provided to the `subtract` method.

From the [dart docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/DateTime/subtract.html) we can see that the `subtract` function takes an argument of type `Duration` and not `DateTime` as the code sample shows.

In order to get a duration value from two datetimes you should use the `difference` method, [Visit the dart docs more info](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/DateTime/difference.html)

Comment: If your issue is resolved, consider marking it as the accepted answer. So we can help others with the same question in the future